# Как просмотреть локальный сайт на телефоне?

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, веб-сайт

Я сделал сайт и адаптировал его под все устройства, но он, как вы понимаете, только на компе. (и в гите) На хостинг заливать буду позже.
Вопрос: Как мне открыть свой сайт на телефоне (пощупать, понажимать, в общем, проверить его перед заливом на хост?) В интернетах толковой инфы не нарыл (хотя искал прилично). Пробовал вариант через ipconfig узнать айпи локальной сети, в итоге набрал на телефоне, а телефон ушёл в вечную загрузку. Отключал брандмауэр, делал сеть домашней, ничего не получается. Что же мне делать?

Comment: В конфигурационном файле вашего локального HTTP сервера нужно создать запись, так чтобы ваш сайт был доступен по локальноой сети по локальному IP адресу вашей серверной машины (обычно это 192.168.0.XXX). Ваш мобильный телефон должен быть в той-же локальной сети (например по WIFI).

Comment: https://browsersync.io/ Поставьте ее себе и открывайте на здоровье.
Кроме того есть экстеншены для браузеров. Их тыщща и один вариант. Загуглите тему.)

Comment: @NoSkill, я думаю, это можно оформить ответом

Comment: @insolor если бы авторы конкретизировали свои вопросы... а так, не известно, какой у автора http-сервер или инструментарий для web-разработчика.

Comment: Когда я с этим столкнулся, то нашел такое решение - установить мобильное приложение **Настройки открытия в браузере**.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос при помощи github pages

Согласно документации - это бесплатный хостинг статический сайтов (html, css, js). Можно залить туда сайт и смотреть его с любого девайса.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages

Answer (score -3):

Для этого, по крайней мере в Опере, есть отдельная кнопка на консоли. [image: вот эта кнопка]

Попробуйте ее:)

И да, оно работает с локальными сайтами.